# Swift / How to call tableViewCell's textLabel.text value?

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I'm having a subclass of UITableViewCell with an Outlet.

```
class UserNewPostCell: UITableViewCell {
@IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!
```

The tableView ist part of a UIViewController

```
class NewUserTweetVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
```

My NewUserTweetVC has a Top-Toolbar with a Button

```
    @IBAction func toolbarPostButton(sender: AnyObject, date: NSDate) {

    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! UserNewPostCell

    let testTweet = cell.textLabel!.text

    postTweet(testTweet!, date: NSDate())

}
```

Problem: `cell.textLabel!.text` = nil. Why? The Placeholder Text is "What's on your mind?" and to make sure I added:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    textView.text = "What's on your mind?"
```

To the Cell. How do I get the value of textLabel.text the way I need it too? Help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting your textView's text (from `@IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!`)  here: `textView.text = "What's on your mind?"`. This is *not* the same as the `cell.textLabel!.text`.

The cell.textLabel is an auto-generated parameter for UITableViewCell used in the standard [UITableViewCellStyles](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UITableViewCellStyle).

You need either stick to using your textView everywhere or the textLabel.

Comment: yes... of course... you're right... it was a typo on auto-code-filling... i didn't noticed and needed almost one hour in researching the mistake... i hate myself... thank you

Comment: Haha no worries, we all make mistakes like this! It sounds like common sense, but if you take a break from the computer for 5-10 minutes and come back you really get a fresh start in identifying pesky bugs like this